# Is it possible to get a kernel backtrace for a process stopped with ptrace/gdb?

Tags: gdb, ptrace, backtrace, libunwind

I'm using `ptrace(2)` and `libunwind` on Linux to sample user-level stacks from a running process, which works well. However, if I try to look at the kernel-level stack in `/proc/<pid>/stack` I always see the following:

```
[<0>] ptrace_stop+0x155/0x270
[<0>] get_signal+0x49e/0x730
[<0>] do_signal+0x34/0x6d0
[<0>] exit_to_usermode_loop+0x82/0xf0
[<0>] do_syscall_64+0x1a3/0x1b0
[<0>] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[<0>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

That is, the current kernel-level stack for the process is in `ptrace_stop()`, not whatever it was doing before (and what I am interested in).

Is there any way to avoid this and read the original kernel-level stack of a process stopped by `ptrace(2)`? I observe the same behaviour for processes attached to a debugger, e.g. `gdb`, so I assume the solution would be the same.